# IIS Worker Process CPU limit with ThrottleUnderLoad

Tags: .net, windows, cpu-usage, iis-8

I have following IIS setup

```
Server
|
|-Application Pools
|-Sites
   |
   |-Website1
      |
      |-Application1
      |-Application2
```

Website1 is running with AppPool WebsiteAppPool
Application1 is running with App Pool Application1AppPool
Application2 is running with App Pool Application2AppPool

WebsiteAppPool is with CPU limit of 50% (i.e. 50000) and limitaction ThrottleUnderLoad
Application1AppPool is with CPU limit of 80% (i.e. 80000) and limitaction ThrottleUnderLoad
Application2AppPool is with CPU limit of 50% (i.e. 50000) and limitaction ThrottleUnderLoad

I was performing load testing on Application1 and other applications are idle.

[image]

Red line is CPU consumption of Application1AppPool, Blue line is CPU consumption of total machine processor time.

When Application1AppPool is at high CPU usage, application started to get errors and response time is unacceptable range.

Now my question is even after giving CPU limit to 80% to Application1AppPool, why it is reaching to 100% (red line) (in the screen it shows near 90% but actually it started to reach 100% when we see less time interval graph) but my machine's CPU is hardly being used (blue line). I was expecting total processor process time to be around 80%.

ThrottleUnderLoad means it can consume more CPU than 80% if there is no CPU contention i.e. no other process is demanding CPU. So theoretically, Application1AppPool was allowed to use more available CPU, which is not happening.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Throttle under load - The application pool worker processes will be throttled at the limit specified only if other applications require the CPU. If the CPU is idle the application pool may consume more CPU activity, exceeding the limit set for it.

it means it can use CPU if require.

if you want to stop the CPU consumption after some limit you could use the "Kill worker processes" action. it will shut down the Application pool worker processes that exceed their CPU limit.

For more information you could refer to the below article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/cpu

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-cpu-throttling-sand-boxing-sites-and-applications

Comment: Yes I understand that that is why my question is why Application1AppPool is reaching to 100% where as 70% machine CPU is idle. Above response is not answer to the question.

Comment: @AsifNowaj could you please share what value you set for the time interval in CPU setting?

Comment: Hi @Jalpa Panchal - It is 5 mins. But time interval with ThrottleUnderLoad action is not in effect. This time interval is there for compatibility for other options. Throttle and ThrottleUnderLoad does not consider time interval.